# NPM 'run start' command giving "npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE" error

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, cmd, npm-start

I'm trying to run NPM with `npm run start` command but I'm getting this error:

```
> @ start C:\Users\Aristophanes
> cd packages/react-scripts && node bin/react-scripts.js start

The system cannot find the path specified.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @ start: `cd packages/react-scripts && node bin/react-scripts.js start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @ start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Does anyone know why this might be happening? Thanks.

Comment: `The system cannot find the path specified.` ... So one of these paths is incorrect: `packages/react-scripts` or `bin/react-scripts.js`

Comment: What is the point of `cd packages/react-scripts`? You seem to only need the node command.

Comment: Hi, the packages path seems to be from `C:\Users\Aristophanes\create-react-app-next\packages\react-scripts\bin\react-scripts.js`. I'm not sure where that folder came from. I also have `C:\Users\Aristophanes\ipfs_image_uploader\client\node_modules\react-scripts\bin\react-scripts.js` and `C:\Users\Aristophanes\node_modules\react-scripts\bin\react-scripts.js` . I'm not sure why I have more than one, what should I do? Thanks.